# Angularjs + Kineticjs mouse events

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kineticjs

I want to use **Angularjs** with **Kineticjs**. The problem is that, it seems angular is overriding mouse events on my stage object.

The following html works fine as **stand alone file**, you can test it. But if you put this as an **Angularjs** template, the mouse events stop working.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
      #container {
        background-color: black;
        background-image: url("http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/line-building.png");
        background-position: 1px 0px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 580px;
        height: 327px;
      }
    </style>
   </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script defer="defer">
  function getData() {
    return {
      '1st Floor': {
        color: 'blue',
        points: [366, 298, 500, 284, 499, 204, 352, 183, 72, 228, 74, 274]
      },
      '2nd Floor': {
        color: 'red',
        points: [72, 228, 73, 193, 340, 96, 498, 154, 498, 191, 341, 171]
      },
      '3rd Floor': {
        color: 'yellow',
        points: [73, 192, 73, 160, 340, 23, 500, 109, 499, 139, 342, 93]
      },
      'Gym': {
        color: 'green',
        points: [498, 283, 503, 146, 560, 136, 576, 144, 576, 278, 500, 283]
      }
    }
  }
  function updateTooltip(tooltip, x, y, text) {
    tooltip.getText().setText(text);
    tooltip.setPosition(x, y);
    tooltip.show();
  }
  var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 578,
    height: 325
  });
  var shapesLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
  var tooltipLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();

  var tooltip = new Kinetic.Label({
    opacity: 0.75,
    visible: false,
    listening: false,
    text: {
      text: '',
      fontFamily: 'Calibri',
      fontSize: 18,
      padding: 5,
      fill: 'white'
    },
    rect: {
      fill: 'black',
      pointerDirection: 'down',
      pointerWidth: 10,
      pointerHeight: 10,
      lineJoin: 'round',
      shadowColor: 'black',
      shadowBlur: 10,
      shadowOffset: 10,
      shadowOpacity: 0.5
    }
  });

  tooltipLayer.add(tooltip);

  // get areas data
  var areas = getData();

  // draw areas
  for(var key in areas) {

    var area = areas[key];
    var points = area.points;

    var shape = new Kinetic.Polygon({
      points: points,
      fill: area.color,
      opacity: 0,
      // custom attr
      key: key
    });

    shapesLayer.add(shape);

  }

  stage.add(shapesLayer);
  stage.add(tooltipLayer);

  stage.on('mouseover', function(evt) {
    var shape = evt.targetNode;
    shape.setOpacity(0.5);
    shapesLayer.draw();
  });
  stage.on('mouseout', function(evt) {
    var shape = evt.targetNode;
    shape.setOpacity(0);
    shapesLayer.draw();
    tooltip.hide();
    tooltipLayer.draw();
  });
  stage.on('mousemove', function(evt) {
    var shape = evt.targetNode;
    var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();
    var x = mousePos.x;
    var y = mousePos.y - 5;
    updateTooltip(tooltip, x, y, shape.attrs.key);
    tooltipLayer.batchDraw();
  }); 

</script>
```

How does **event handling** work on angular? And how could I prevent from overriding events like:

```
stage.on('mouseover', function(evt) {
    var shape = evt.targetNode;
    shape.setOpacity(0.5);
    shapesLayer.draw();
  });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it seems Angular was capturing all DOM events.

The solution is to put **Kineticjs**  tag before **angular.js**(and probably before jQuery too), and be sure you **don't declare the tag again elsewhere** in any view.